# I have accidentally set up my path environment variable incorrectly using the .bash_profile on macbook. How do I reset it?

Tags: bash, macos

> -bash: export: /Users/deboadebayo/Desktop/Coding/:/opt/anaconda3/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin':
>   not a valid identifier

The above message is the error message I receive every time I open my terminal. I did create a backup of my bash profile. But essentially now I can no longer navigate anywhere I want to go using command line requests.

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Why not open the broken file and fix whatever is broken?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

oops.  The easiest way to fix it would be to launch an editor with an *absolute path*.  $PATH only specifies the locations in which the shell will search if told to execute a program relative (or no) path specified.  The `which` program can search the path and shows the first executable found:

```
$ which vim
/usr/bin/vim
```

So if you're a `vim` user, you should be able to run `/usr/bin/vim` at the command line, and the path won't be relevant.  Then you can fix your file in the editor.  Looks like my osx machine also has `nano` if you'd prefer that editor.  I don't think I installed it so it probably came shipped with osx I'm guessing:

```
$ which nano
/usr/bin/nano
```

If you want to revert to your backup, use `cp`, but specify it from its absolute position, `/bin/cp`:

```
$ /bin/cp first.txt second.txt
```

Obviously you'll want to change the file names on that one for it to work for you.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a backup, use an absolute path to the `mv` and `cp` commands to rename your broken file and restore the backup, both without depending on path lookup.

```
/bin/mv .bash_profile .bash_profile.broken
/bin/cp .bash_profile.backup .bash_profile
```

Close the current terminal window and open a new one, which should use your working, original `.bash_profile` to initialize `PATH`. Now you try to make the *correct* modification to your `PATH`.